# two similar pg_query statements, one is OK, the other FAILS. Why?

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, where-clause

I am having a confusion on what is happening. So I just need some ideas or clarifications.

I have 3 PHP variables and two PostgreSQL queries:

```
$date_start = $d1 = "2013-01-01";
$date_end = $d2 = "2013-01-05";
$car = "x";

$query_1 = pg_query($con, "SELECT AVG(longitude) as lon, AVG(latitude) as lat, MAX(longitude) as maxlon, MIN(longitude) as minlon, MAX(latitude) as maxlat, MIN(latitude) as minlat FROM table WHERE car='".$car."' AND testdate>='".$date_start."' AND testdate<='".$date_end."'";

$query_2 = pg_query($con, "SELECT MIN(testtime) as t1, MAX(testtime) as t2 FROM table WHERE car='$car' AND testdate>='$d1' AND testdate=<'$d2' GROUP BY testdate");
```

The trouble here is that $query_1 gets through fine and gives me a proper result resource, while the other one is always false with an error message:

```
ERROR: operator does not exist: date =< unknown
LINE 1: ... car='BM1' AND testdate>='2013-04-04' AND testdate=<'2013-04...
^
HINT: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

So... any ideas what is happening there? I am sure the queries are almost the same, but for the reason I do not understand PostgreSQL is complaining about one but not the other!

I do **not** need help on how to fix this, I just need to know the **reason**. Why the behaviour is different..

Cheers!!

Yours
Andy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not a postgress expert but AFAIK there is no **=<** operator but **<=**

```
$query_2 = pg_query($con, "SELECT MIN(testtime) as t1, MAX(testtime) as t2 FROM table WHERE car='$car' AND testdate>='$d1' AND testdate=<'$d2' GROUP BY testdate");
```

Comment: Indeed! A tiny typo which I was unable to see! Thank yOu! :)